# Changing to same value of one group of data

Tags: r

If I have this data

```
ID, Freq
1,15
1,15
1,15
1,5
2,10
2,10
2,15
```

I would like to change them like this

```
1,15
1,15
1,15
1,15
2,10
2,10
2,10
```

Maybe someone can help me for this. Thanks

Comment: they have more duplication than  the other, 15 is 3 times and 10 is 2 times. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be a better way, but one way using `dplyr` would be to calculate occurrence of each `Freq` by group (`ID`), `sort` them in decreasing order and `mutate` the first one for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Freq = names(sort(table(Freq), decreasing = TRUE)[1]))


#     ID Freq 
#   <int> <chr>
#1     1 15   
#2     1 15   
#3     1 15   
#4     1 15   
#5     2 10   
#6     2 10   
#7     2 10
```

---

We can also use `which.max`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Freq = names(which.max(table(Freq))))
```

---

Base R translation using `ave`

```
df$Freq <- with(df, ave(Freq, ID, FUN = function(x) names(which.max(table(x)))))


df$Freq <- with(df, ave(Freq, ID, FUN = function(x) 
                  names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1])))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Freq = c(15L, 
15L, 15L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 15L)), .Names = c("ID", "Freq"), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-7L))
```